# SQL Insert duplicating values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert data in SQL table, but it's duplicating the values:

```
    $star1 = trim($_GET['star1']);
    $star2 = trim($_GET['star2']);
    $star3 = trim($_GET['star3']);
    $star4 = trim($_GET['star4']);
    $star5 = trim($_GET['star5']);

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Desculpe.. Falha ao salvar ");
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO classificacoes (nossa_empresa, produtos_oferecidos,atendimento, colaboradores, indicaria) VALUES ('$star1','$star2','$star3','$star4', '$star5')";
    $conn->query($sql); 
    if ($conn->query($sql) != TRUE){
        echo "Erro ao gravar";
    }
    else{
        echo "Gravou";
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
```

That is: The code insert two identincal values in the table.

What's wrong?

Comment: because, you're querying twice.

Comment: personally, I feel this question doesn't warrant an answer, it's a typo IMHO.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yeah, thanks for the tip. I'll fix it soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're running the query twice:

```
 $conn->query($sql); 
 if ($conn->query($sql) != TRUE){
```

The `if` line is also running the query, so you should remove the line above the `if`. Your code should be like this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO classificacoes (nossa_empresa, produtos_oferecidos,atendimento, colaboradores, indicaria) VALUES ('$star1','$star2','$star3','$star4', '$star5')";
 if ($conn->query($sql) != TRUE){
     echo "Erro ao gravar";
 }
```

Or another option is to get the result of the query in a variable, like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO classificacoes (nossa_empresa, produtos_oferecidos,atendimento, colaboradores, indicaria) VALUES ('$star1','$star2','$star3','$star4', '$star5')";
$insertOK = $conn->query($sql)
if ($insertOK != TRUE){ // This is equal to if(!$insertOK){
    echo "Erro ao gravar";
}
```